# C# Altering TIFF Photometric Interpretation

Tags: c#, tiff, aforge

I have the following method that resizes an image and returns the newly resized image as a TIFF (I am using the AForge library which is where the ResizeBilinear object comes from).

```
private System.Drawing.Image shrinkImageBilinear(System.Drawing.Image original, float newWidthInches, float newHeightInches)
    {
        float imageProportion = (float)original.Width / (float)original.Height;
        float newWidthPixels = original.HorizontalResolution * newWidthInches;
        float newHeightPixels = newWidthPixels / imageProportion;

        ResizeBilinear filter = new ResizeBilinear((int)newWidthPixels, (int)newHeightPixels);
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(original);
        image = filter.Apply(image);
        Rectangle imageRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Size.Width, image.Size.Height);
        image = image.Clone(imageRect, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);

        MemoryStream byteStream = new MemoryStream();
        image.SetResolution(200, 200);

        image.Save(byteStream, ImageFormat.Tiff);

        Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(byteStream);
        return returnImage;
    }
```

The specification that I need to write to is that the Photometric Interpretation in the TIFF header cannot leverage a color palette, therefore the Photometric Interpretation can only be a 0 or 1, in this case it is a 3 since I am using PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed. Another requirement in the spec I am writing to is that the image must be 1bpp.

So my question is, how can I create this image without leveraging a color palette (thereby making the photometric interpretation a 1 or 0), maintaining 1bpp, keeping the resolution at 200 ppi and keeping the format as a TIFF?

Answer (score 0):

if youd look into the aforge code itself, (download full source) you will enough notes to find your answer.